# How can I find out the version of mysql package?

Tags: package-management, mysql, versions

In Lubuntu 18.04, I found `mysql-client-core-5.7` in default repositories. I was wondering which version of mysql it provides? I don't find any such information in https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/mysql-client-core-5.7, and where can I look it up?

The most recent mysql is 8.0.11 version. 5.7 seems too old to be the real version.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't judge by the jump in version numbers. 8.0 was released in [April 2018](https://mysqlserverteam.com/whats-new-in-mysql-8-0-generally-available/), just days before 18.04 came out. There's no way it would have been included in 18.04. As for the jump, I think they dropped in the `5` in `5.8` and moved to `8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lastest mysql client/server officially supported by Ubuntu 18.04 is version 5.7. Unless you added PPA for later version of mysql, you can check the versions of the support package.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-cache show mysql-server
sudo apt-cache show mysql-client
```

The first few lines should provide the information you seek.

```
Package: mysql-server
Architecture: all
Version: 5.7.22-0ubuntu18.04.1
Priority: optional
Section: database
Source: mysql-5.7
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>

Package: mysql-client
Architecture: all
Version: 5.7.22-0ubuntu18.04.1
Priority: optional
Section: database
Source: mysql-5.7
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
```

If you wish to install newer version than that, you'll need to add the mysql repository, just follow the instructions [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/).